# How to know if Facebook token is long-live or short-live

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm building api for a project and i need to use facebook api, i have understood that the client get a short-live accessToken sent this token to the server, the server get a long-live accessToken and send back to the client, this is my code for this:

```
$token = Request::header('token');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => Config::get('facebook.app_id'),
      'secret' => Config::get('facebook.app_secret'),
));
$facebook->setAccessToken($token);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user==0){
      return 'invalid token';
}
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$newToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
return $newToken;
```

After that the client will save the newToken for the future requests, the problme is that the next time the client will send me a long-live token then i don't need to exchange the token with a long-live token because it's already a long-live token, how i can know if the token is long-live or short-live?

Comment: Why do client sends you tokens? For me: When user registers I get his/her token and it always short. Then change it to long living token and save pair application_user_id and long_living_access_token in database/

Comment: i use loggin with facebook then with JS the user does login with facebook and if the client want to send a request has to send the facebookToken, the server check if the facebookToken is valid, if it's valid then the user is logged in otherwise the user is invalid

Comment: 1. You registered user and you store user's id. If javascript SDK response "connected", then you can get session using FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper and retrieve all information that you need, then send request for long access token and store it.
2. When user come back you can retrieve long access token from database using user id, that was previously stored. Access token as key to user is IMHO bad idea because it often changes and expires even if it is long (2 months or so, not infinity)

Comment: Why are you sending the long-lived token back to the client? There is hardly any need to use long-lived tokens on the client-side, because the JS SDK will see to it that you always have a valid short-lived token.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `debug_token` endpoint for facebook's graph:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/debug_token

The token is a short lived token if `data.issued_at` is not set.